# How does gradle determine the version of a transtive dependency when using "integration platform(xxx.bom)"

Tags: java, maven, gradle

java experts, I have a gradle project and import a BOM like below :

```
implementation platform("eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:${project.property("dssBomVersion")}")
```

when I use the command "gradlew dependencyInsight" to check the version of one transtive dependency jaxb-runtime,  I get the version of jaxb-runtime is upradeded from 2.3.9 to 4.0.4.

```
./gradlew <my_project_name>:dependencyInsight --configuration=runtimeClasspath --dependency org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime


> Task :grdc-signing-service:dependencyInsight
org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.4
  Variant runtime:
    | Attribute Name                 | Provided     | Requested    |
    |--------------------------------|--------------|--------------|
    | org.gradle.status              | release      |              |
    | org.gradle.category            | library      | library      |
    | org.gradle.libraryelements     | jar          | jar          |
    | org.gradle.usage               | java-runtime | java-runtime |
    | org.gradle.dependency.bundling |              | external     |
    | org.gradle.jvm.environment     |              | standard-jvm |
    | org.gradle.jvm.version         |              | 17           |
   Selection reasons:
      - Selected by rule
      - By constraint

org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.9 -> 4.0.4
+--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13
|    \--- runtimeClasspath
+--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-jaxb-common:5.13
|    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-xmldsig:5.13
|    |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-validation-report:5.13
|    |    |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:validation-policy:5.13
|    |    |         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |         \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-document:5.13
|    |    |              +--- runtimeClasspath (requested eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-document)
|    |    |              +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |              +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-cades:5.13
|    |    |              |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |              |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-pades:5.13
|    |    |              |         +--- runtimeClasspath (requested eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-pades)
|    |    |              |         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |              |         \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-pades-pdfbox:5.13
|    |    |              |              +--- runtimeClasspath (requested eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-pades-pdfbox)
|    |    |              |              \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |              \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-xades:5.13
|    |    |                   +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |                   \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-tsl-validation:5.13
|    |    |                        +--- runtimeClasspath (requested eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-tsl-validation)
|    |    |                        \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-trusted-list:5.13
|    |    |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |    |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-tsl-validation:5.13 (*)
|    |    |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-validation-report:5.13 (*)
|    |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-xades:5.13
|    |         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|    |         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-validation-report:5.13 (*)
|    |         \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-trusted-list:5.13 (*)
|    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-jaxb-parsers:5.13
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-validation-report:5.13 (*)
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-trusted-list:5.13 (*)
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:specs-xades:5.13 (*)
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-policy-jaxb:5.13
|         |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|         |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:validation-policy:5.13 (*)
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-diagnostic-jaxb:5.13
|         |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|         |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:validation-policy:5.13 (*)
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-simple-report-jaxb:5.13
|         |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|         |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:validation-policy:5.13 (*)
|         +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-simple-certificate-report-jaxb:5.13
|         |    +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|         |    \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:validation-policy:5.13 (*)
|         \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-detailed-report-jaxb:5.13
|              +--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-bom:5.13 (*)
|              \--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:validation-policy:5.13 (*)
\--- eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-jaxb-parsers:5.13 (*)

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

But when I checked the content of the BOM file, I didn't see it specify the version of JAXB-runtime, neither 2.3.9 nor 4.0.4,  see
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/eu/europa/ec/joinup/sd-dss/dss-bom/5.13/dss-bom-5.13.pom,
And
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/eu/europa/ec/joinup/sd-dss/dss-jaxb-common/5.13/dss-jaxb-common-5.13.pom

So Could you help me understand how gradle resolve the jaxb-runtime version should be upgraded to 4.0.4? Thank you.

Comment: solved. Solved. the strange behaviour is caused by spring dependency management plugin. Once it's removed and we specify the spring BOM explicitly use gradle native BOM support, then it will show how Jaxb-runtime version is determined to be 4.0.4 clearly.